# Missing values using group by with pivot request

Tags: mysql

Here, is the database that I have :

```
| id | name    | type   | nom     | note |
|  1 | kiwi    | fruit  | Michel  |   14 |  
|  2 | kiwi    | fruit  | Jean    |    7 |  
|  3 | kiwi    | fruit  | Laurent |   18 |  
|  4 | fraise  | fruit  | Michel  |   10 |  
|  5 | fraise  | fruit  | Laurent |   12 |  
|  6 | poireau | legume | Michel  |   10 |
```

I would like to have a result like this :

```
| id       | name    | Michel | Jean | Laurent |
| kiwi     | fruit   |     14 |    7 |      18 |  
| fraise   | fruit   |     10 | NULL |      12 |  
| poireau  | legume  |     10 | NULL |    NULL |
```

So, I tried to pivot the column `nom`, to have the `note` for each `nom` according to `name` and `type`.

This is not my real database and I don't have a static number of `nom`, `name`, `type` and `note`. Everything is dynamic so I tried a dynamical way to do it

```
set @sql=null;  
select group_concat(distinct 'case when nom = ''', nom,''' then note end as ',replace(nom, ' ', '')) into @sql from products;  
set @sql = concat('select name, type, ', @sql, ' from products group by name, type');  
prepare stmt from @sql;  
execute stmt;
```

Result :

**| name    | type   | Michel | Jean | Laurent |**
| fraise  | fruit  |     10 | NULL |    NULL |
| kiwi    | fruit  |     14 | NULL |    NULL |
| poireau | legume |     10 | NULL |    NULL |

Unfortunately, the pivot was good but the `note` belongs to `Jean` and `Laurent` were missing.

I tried the same request without `group by`.

```
set @sql=null;  
select group_concat(distinct 'case when nom = ''', nom,''' then note end as ',replace(nom, ' ', '')) into @sql from products;  
set @sql = concat('select name, type, ', @sql, ' from products');  
prepare stmt from @sql;  
execute stmt;
```

Result :

**| name    | type   | Michel | Jean | Laurent |**
| kiwi    | fruit  |     14 | NULL |    NULL |
| kiwi    | fruit  |   NULL |    7 |    NULL |
| kiwi    | fruit  |   NULL | NULL |      18 |
| fraise  | fruit  |     10 | NULL |    NULL |
| fraise  | fruit  |   NULL | NULL |      12 |
| poireau | legume |     10 | NULL |    NULL |

The `name` column is not group but all the `note` were there !

What I want, it's a group by `name` and all the `note` belongs to each `nom`

Thank you for your help !

**Answer :**

> set @sql=null;
>   select group_concat(distinct 'max(case when nom = ''', nom,''' then note end) as ',replace(nom, ' ', '')) into @sql from products;
>   set @sql = concat('select name, type, ', @sql, ' from products group by name, type');
>   prepare stmt from @sql;
>   execute stmt;

Comment: You need to include your table structure here in the question along with the queries you have tried.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO, please be aware that we are not a free coding service. As already mentioned, add your tables structure and data directly on the question as text (we will help to format it) here, that will make it easier to others use your data and structure to test purposes. Also and it is very important add your attempt to solve the problem. We are more prone to help people that demonstrate effort.

Comment: You can construct mobile phone ringtones, maps of the earth, and snowflakes in MySQL, but just because you *can*, it doesn't immediately follow that you *should*. Seriously consider handling issues of data display in a presentation layer.

Comment: The `@sql` should have a `max()` for each column and in the final query you group it by name and type. That should do what you need.

Comment: Thank You !! that works perfectly !